# what does it mean of "Collection is a Framework"?

Tags: java

Actually I am learning Java and stuck on "Collection" .  Can any body explain what does it mean by :-"Collection is a frame work" . I am a bit confused . Is it a pre-written programmes? is it a environment to build project. Kindly explain. Your help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It's just a meaningless misquotation from something you read somewhere. Have another look.

Answer (score 4):

"Collection is a Framework" is incorrect, but you can see how someone would make that mistake.

Java has the *Collections framework*, which is a group of classes and interfaces provided by the JDK that handle collections of things like lists and maps and sets. They're in the [`java.util` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) (along with a bunch of other things that aren't part of the Collections framework).

More about the collections framework in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Comment: Thank you @T.J. Crowder.. link gave me a clear idea about collection. Thanks a lot.